# passing a string with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python. I'm using python 3.1.2 I've to communicate to the xml-rpc server through my code. From my code, I'm calling the client.py that will in-turn connect to the server to get the lists of comments from the server.

The working code:

```python
class xmlrpc:
    def connect(self, webaddr):
        self.server = ServerProxy(webaddr)
```

Listing the method:-

```
my_list = self.server.tests.getTests()
```

the above method is working, but, whereas i've constraint to set the `tests.getTests()` into a single `cmd_str` like below

```
my_list = self.server.cmd_str
```

in this case, `cmd_str` sent to the client.py as a string itself and not like other one.  Could anyone pls help me how to acheive this?

Comment: I'm having a really hard time figuring out what you are asking.  Can you rephrase "in this case, cmd_str sent to the client.py as a string itself and not like other one" or add some examples?

Comment: sorry about that.. What I'm trying to say is, in my program, I've hardcoded cmd_str to tests.getTests() and passing it to client.py .. but, when the client.py reads it, it considers cmd_str as a value and not tests.getTests(). How can I pass the value of cmd_str?

Comment: If I put it in a simple way, how to get print executed?         class Server:
        def isRunning():
                    print("you are inside the isRunning")
    
    
cmdStr="isRunning()"
test=Server.cmdStr

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to call a method of an object, but you don't know the method in advance, you just have it in a string. Is that correct?

```
class Server(object): 
    def isRunning(self): 
        print("you are inside the isRunning")

my_server = Server()
cmd_str = "isRunning"
my_function = my_server.__getattribute__(cmd_str)
my_function()
```

> you are inside the isRunning

Note that I let the `Server` class inherit from `object` to make it a so-called new-style class, and that `isRunning` gets an argument `self`, which tells python that this should be an instance method. `my_server.__getattribute__` will get a reference to the bound function `my_server.isRunning`, which you then call.

You could also do something like this:

```
function_map = {
    'check_if_running': my_server.isRunning
}
cmd_str = 'check_if_running'
my_function = function_map[cmd_str]
my_function()
```

so you don't have to name your functions exactly the way that your command strings are called (in python, the naming convention for methods is generally `like_this`, not `likeThis`)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, what you need is to call a method which you have only the name in a string, not a reference to the method itself.

You could use the [getattr](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm) function to get a reference to the method you want to call.

Using it in your example:

```
cmdStr = "isRunning" 
func = getattr(Server, cmdStr)
test = func()
```